# The most trivial lookup on maps seems to return an Option[Something]

Tags: scala, maps

I know that maps results are split into

- None
- Some

However I would like to only get back (when using a lookup) the actual object that is being pointed towards. Let me make myself a bit more clear:

I have the map abc

```
val abc = Map( 1 -> List("a","b"), 2 -> List("z","y") )
```

And I want to somehow get back

```
List("a","b")
```

I tried:

```
abc(1) // return a List
```

I tried to pattern match:

```
abc get 1 match {
  case Some(x) => x
}
```

But the pattern match returns an Object

I tried to achieve this using a for :

```
(for((int, string) <- abc; if(int == 1)) yield string)
```

But it returns an Immutable iterator object.

I know this answer is very very basic but I can't get my head around this and I can't find anything on the internet that relates to this

Comment: What on earth are you doing to get an `Option`? `abc(1) = List("a","b")`.

Comment: `abc(1)` definitely isn't an `Option` (which is why it's such a terrible idea).

Comment: My bad. abc(1) for me is `res2: Object`. What I want is a `List`

Comment: It seems that you are using Java Map, have some conversions taking place, or maybe you declared your Map somewhere as `Map[Int, Object]`? Check your imports, or prefix the Map with the package to check: `scala.collection.immutable.Map`.

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov check comment on answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REPLed it up:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_05).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val abc = Map( 1 -> List("a","b"), 2 -> List("z","y") )
abc: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[String]] = Map(1 -> List(a, b), 2 -> List(z, y))
```

I see a difference here: You got an Option. But I got the List back. As you can see, I am on Scala 2.10.4

```
scala> abc(1)
res0: List[String] = List(a, b)

scala> abc get 1 match { case Some(x) => x }
<console>:9: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: None
              abc get 1 match { case Some(x) => x }
                  ^
res1: List[String] = List(a, b)
```

Again, I see something different than what you see. I got back a List and not an Object.

```
scala> (for((int, string) <- abc; if(int == 1)) yield string)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[List[String]] = List(List(a, b))
```

Yes, I got an immutable Iterator[List[String]] back. If you just need the List[String] type you can as well do this:

```
scala> res2.toList.flatMap(identity)
res3: List[String] = List(a, b)
```

Basically `identity` function boils down to this:

```
scala> res2.toList.flatMap(i => i)
res4: List[String] = List(a, b)
```

Or you can even do this:

```
scala> res2.toList.flatten
res5: List[String] = List(a, b)
```

Some points: You should avoid apply on a Map and do a `get` because you will see this:

```
scala> abc(3)
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: 3

scala> abc.get(3)
res7: Option[List[String]] = None
```

I prefer something like:

```
scala> abc.get(1).getOrElse(List.empty[String])
res10: List[String] = List(a, b)
```

Comment: Looks like what I did was added a default value using the withDefaultValue to my map and this caused the brackets to return an Object. I will accept this answer because it's so detailed however you might wish to add that adding a default value will cause one to get different values than expected

Answer (score 2):

You probably added a default value to the map that only has Object as common supertype with List.

The withDefaultValue method uses a lower type bound on the type of the values in the Map. So when you do `Map( 1 -> List("a","b"), 2 -> List("z","y") ) .withDefaultValue("x")` the result will be a `Map[Int, Object]`